# Database consistency when working with FastAPI + gunicorn

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi, wsgi, consistency

I am slightly confused with the idea of running FastAPI with gunicorn and worker threads while having a central PostgreSQL database.
I have a synchronous FastAPI application that is a REST API to the database. However, when handling multiple concurrent HTTP requests, two or more worker threads processing the request will simultaneously operate on the same DB. If one request A is asking for an item while at the same time the other request B is deleting that item it will create a consistency issue.
Is this a thing to be concerned about, or does PostgreSQL internally handle this?

I've read from this [link](https://www.postgresql.org/files/developer/concurrency.pdf) that Postgres "snapshots" transactions, therefore, request A might get a different result depending on the order of its transaction execution. (I might have interpreted it wrong, correct me if that's the case).

Please help me understand this problem. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen [the Postgres documentation about how it supports transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html)? This is not a problem specific to fastapi or postgresql, but is usually adjusted depending on your exact needs. "ACID" is usually the term to describe a few of the issues you're wondering about; but this is a large area of information, probably not well-suited for SO. Whether it's something to be concerned about depends on your exact use-case, but generally you'll be fine as long as you've used methods to ensure data integrity (such as foreign keys).